# Uninstall of software

Tags: uninstall

Sometimes when I install software using the `sudo apt-get install <package>` command the package may take minutes to be installed and in the end it may occupy some gb of space. If I uninstall it using `sudo apt-get purge <package>` then it may be uninstalled in seconds and very little space (some kb or mb) may be removed from the original that it occupied when installed! Obviously that means that this is not a clean uninstall and that my pc is full of undeleted files. Why is that happening and how should I uninstall packages cleanly and fully?

Comment: What do you mean by "cleanly and fully"? When a package is removed or a file on the drive is deleted, the space on the drive is available for new files. The data does not in any way need to be over written for the space to be available.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I don't mean to be overwritten! Most times when I uninstall a package then if it occupied upon installation let say 3gb if I uninstall it then those 3 will be back free again. But sometimes this doesn't happen. If when installed occupied 3 then at the end it may free only some mb.

Comment: Even better can you give us an example?

Comment: @Richard Yes wine and texlive. Those two left almost no free space at the end. I mean they both took 5-7 minutes to install and they were uninstalled in under 5 seconds!

Comment: I think 3 Gb is a bit of an exaggeration for the disk space taken by wine when it is installed. With that said, my guess is that you are seeing configuration or data files in your home directory. When you remove a package, see man apt-get. `remove` leaves config files on the system, `purge` removes config files. Both options leave files in /home/your_user. For wine you have /home/your_user/.wine which acts like a "C drive" and can be quite large. That is my best guess from what you have posted.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen 3 bg is what texlive left behind, but thank you for your help.

Comment: 3 Gb sounds more like user data. When I run "apt-get install texlive" I get a long list of dependencies and finally "Need to get 333 MB of archives.
After this operation, 637 MB of additional disk space will be used." This is not exactly 3 Gb. You need to post additional information on where you get the 3 Gb from.

Comment: Ok I will try if I find the chance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you install a package, it may also need to install dependencies for it to work - for instance installing [`torcs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/torcs) (e.g. with `sudo apt-get install torcs`), it needs [`torcs-data`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/torcs-data) etc to work - they are also installed, and are fairly large in size (so also take time to download etc).

When removing `torcs` (e.g. with `sudo apt-get remove torcs`), it will likely leave the `torcs-data` packages and other no longer needed packages behind, taking up space. You can solve this by running `sudo apt-get autoremove <package>`, or `sudo apt-get autoremove` after removing it with `purge`/`remove`.

You can also you the `--purge` option with `autoremove` to remove left over configuration files.

An extra way of clearing space is to use `sudo apt-get clean`, to clear out the repo information and cached packages which also take up space. You will likely need to run `sudo apt-get update` afterwards.

Here are the relevant entries from [the manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/apt-get.8.html):

```
   purge
       purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
       purged (any configuration files are deleted too).

   clean
       clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files.
       It removes everything but the lock file from
       /var/cache/apt/archives/ and /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/. When
       APT is used as a dselect(8) method, clean is run automatically.
       Those who do not use dselect will likely want to run apt-get clean
       from time to time to free up disk space.

   autoremove
       autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically
       installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no
       more needed.
```

Comment: So after an uninstall this should be used in order for one to say that he actually removed a package from his system?

Comment: If the package has already been removed, `sudo apt-get autoremove` should be enough to remove the leftover dependences. Usually apt-get does a notification in this sort of situation, something along the lines of `there will be/are leftover packages, use apt-get autoremove to remove them`